# Stack Overflow account has disappeared

Tags: support, accounts

When trying to log in to my Stack Overflow account, it claims that there isn't any account linked to my email address.

When trying to log in to my Stack Overflow account, it hasn't let me because of wrong user name and password. I have asked for a password reset and I have received a message telling me that there wasn't any account linked to that user. Although I was 99% sure that the username was correct, I have checked Google for the autocompletion of logins. The email was correct; my account has just disappeared, with all my questions, answers and badges. Is there anywhere or anyone who I may address to check whether there is some way to recover my account?

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of your questions and/or answers?

Comment: Out of curiosity, had that account been inactive for a long time? (not that that should make a difference, since [automatic-account-deletion of inactive accounts doesn't happen anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310516/997587)). Or had it gotten suspended several times? (which [might lead to explusion](/conduct) for additional violations)

Comment: Re *"checked Google"*: Do you mean (Google) Chrome?

Comment: - I have not tried with my gmail address, as it is not the one linked to my account
- I haven't checked if I have links to my questions/answers, but I cannot recall having one
- my account is regularly accessed
- Yes, that's right, the section of autocompletion of my google account, just to check that I was not wrong about my user/pass

Answer (score 5):

You can contact Stack Exchange Inc using [their contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). Select the radiobutton that says "Account Issue". In the next sub radiogroup, I'd probably go with "I need to add or remove login credentials", and then use the textarea to describe the problem you're having. Remember to also link to that account's profile page (if you can find it. If you can't find it, include say so).